# Why doesn't this return the correct mysql result?

Tags: mysql

When I use the following query, "tasks" is not returned correctly. It seems that it just picks a random row from the "projects_categories" table or sometimes "tasks" returns NULL, even though all rows in "projects_categories" have a value in that column. What am I missing here? Is the subquery incorrect?

```
SELECT c.id AS continent,
       (SELECT `id` FROM `projects_categories` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1) AS categoryid,
       (SELECT `tasks` FROM `projects_categories` WHERE `id`=categoryid) AS tasks
FROM continents c
     LEFT JOIN projects p  
               ON c.id=p.continent
GROUP BY c.id
HAVING COUNT(p.id) < 3
```

This query will return, for example, one of the following right now:

```
continent: 1, categoryid: 2, tasks: NULL
continent: 1, categoryid: 2, tasks: 12
```

It should however return:

```
continent: 1, categoryid: 2, tasks: 10
```

A simple version of the projects_categories table:

```
INSERT INTO `projects_categories` (`id`, `icon`, `tasks`)
VALUES ('1', '4', '12') ('2', '4', '10') ('3', '4', '12') ('4', '4', '10')
```

A simple version of the continents table:

```
INSERT INTO `continents` (`id`, `name`)
VALUES ('1', 'Europe') ('2', 'North America')
```

A simple version of the projects table:

```
INSERT INTO `projects` (`id`, `continent`)
VALUES ('1', '1') ('1', '2') ('2', '1') ('2', '2') ('2', '3') ('3', '1') ('3', '2')
```

EDIT: it seems that somehow it has something to do with the RAND() statement in the first subquery. The second subquery is doing the RAND() from the first subquery again, so the second subquery gets a different result than it should.

Comment: How would anybody know without knowing what data this query is executed on. Please provide your input data and the expected/desired query result.

Comment: I have now added the data.

Comment: Added the expected result. It seems it has something to do with the RAND() statement btw.

Answer (score 0):

You've not attempted to find out why the quesry is not behaving as you expect. There's an awful lot in that first query which is irrelevant to the behaviour you describe (although it may contain results you are interested in - but I'm struggling to imagine how). If you try...

```
SELECT c.id AS continent,
FROM continents c
     LEFT JOIN projects p  
               ON c.id=p.continent
GROUP BY c.id
HAVING COUNT(p.id) < 3
```

Since inclusion of continents records in the output is contingent on multiple projects, the LEFT JOIN is innappropriate.

Try to find out why this is not working by including some more information about the projects table....

```
SELECT c.id AS continent, COUNT(p.id), GROUP_CONCAT(p.id)
FROM continents c
     INNER JOIN projects p  
               ON c.id=p.continent
GROUP BY c.id
```

Its hard to be more specific when that query will return exactly the right result but its far from clear what result you are expecting.